# PHP SESSION array ends up in error

Tags: php, session

Quick PHP Question.
I am kinda newb to PHP so bear with me.

Why this ends up with 500 server error?

```
<?php
//session start
session_start();

//one time ticket is issued
$ticket = md5(uniqid(mt_rand),TRUE);

//put var ticket in SESSION array which is used in next page.
$_SESSION['ticket'][] = $ticket;

...

$_SESSION['ticketPOST'] = $_POST['ticket'];

...

//functionize htmlspecialchars
function h($string) {
    return htmlspecialchars($string, ENT_QUOTES);
}

?>
```

in same file down below, I wrote something like this:

```
<form action="brahbrah.php" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="ticket" value="<?php echo h($ticket); ?>">
<input type="submit" name="indexForm" value="preview">
</form>
```

any help appreciated.
Thanx.

Comment: please tell is it 500 error or some PHP error ? your code seems to generate php error ?

Comment: I guess both. Strange thing that when I change $_SESSION['ticket'][] = $ticket; to $_SESSION['ticket'] = $ticket; (omit square bracket), this works fine. So this means PHP code error, right?

Comment: I modified my code example and made it more detailed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
$ticket = md5(uniqid(mt_rand()),TRUE);
```

mt_rand is a function and you forgot to put `()`

Comment: The type of error depends on his error settings in his php.ini file. I believe that he will get a 500 Internal Server error if he does not have his display_errors set to On.

Comment: I tried 
    $ticket = md5(uniqid(mt_rand()),TRUE);
and
    $ticket = md5(uniqid(mt_rand(),TRUE));
both did not work. Does this have to do with my PHP.ini's settig?
I will try correcting it too.

Comment: Wait
I modified it like this and worked fine somehow.

$ticket = md5(uniqid(mt_rand(),TRUE));

Answer (score 1):

See this link :http://php.net/manual/en/function.mt-rand.php

Try this code:

```
<?php
//session start
session_start();

//one time ticket is issued
$ticket = md5(uniqid(mt_rand()),TRUE);

//put var ticket to SESSION array which is used in next page.
$_SESSION['ticket'][] = $ticket;

...
?>
```

`mt_rand` required `()`

Comment: Thanx Mariya. I forgot to put it.

Answer (score 0):

Set
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    ini_set('display_errors', true);

And see what an error

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I use BLUEHOST as my test server. I configured php.ini which is located in public_html/ like 'error_reporting  =  E_ALL' but I still get 500 internal server error...